# Elasticsearch 5.0 batch document ingestion with pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I'm upgrading elasticsearch 2.1 to 5.0. I used a document ingestion plugin for 2.1 which works most excellently with a batch ingest.

For 5.0 I've installed the ingest-attachment in 5.0.

I've created a pipeline:

```
{
  "attachment": {
  "description": "Attachment ingestion",
  "processors": [
    {
      "attachment": {
        "field": "data"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

The problem is, with the previous plugin I was ingesting using bulk, but I can't find in the documentation how to do a bulk ingest whilst utilising a pipeline?

Comment: You'd do the exact same way using bulk, the only change is that you need to specify the pipeline name in your bulk call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right @val, it was a case of rtm!

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  client.bulk({
    body: documentArray,
    pipeline: 'attachment',//this worked
  }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      return reject(error.message);
    }

    resolve(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!